# Libgcrypt warning: MD5 used - FIPS mode inactivated

Tags: centos, security

Last week I [enabled the openSSH FIPS 140-2 module](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-Federal_Standards_And_Regulations-Federal_Information_Processing_Standard.html) on Server "A", and that system works flawlessly (including tsql queries to a SQL Server instance).

I recently [enabled the openSSH FIPS 140-2 module](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-Federal_Standards_And_Regulations-Federal_Information_Processing_Standard.html) on a CentOS 6.7 system. After rebooting, fips showed enabled and tested OK - but `tsql` stopped working with the following error:

```
[serverB ~]# tsql -S egServer80 -U myusername
Password: 
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 20002 (severity 9):
    Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

I check the log files and find this:

```
tsql: Libgcrypt warning: MD5 used - FIPS mode inactivated
```

Enabling debug in freetds yielded this additional error:

```
14:56:46.617196 3577 (net.c:1366):'''handshake failed: GnuTLS internal error.
```

Backing out the FIPS module (removing fips=1 from grub.conf) and rebooting set things back and I was again able to `tsql` into my SQL Server instance.

**Why (or how) is enabling FIPS in grub causing `libgcrypt` to fail on this one machine?**

---

**NOTE #1:**

I can reproduce the `tsql` problem on without enabling FIPS 140-2 in grub, by creating an empty file `/etc/gcrypt/fips_enabled`. Removing this file sets the system back to normal, and `tsql` works again.

**Additional Information**

```
libgcrypt version 1.4.5
freetds version 0.91
openssl version 1.0.1e
CentOS version 6.7
```